# how to define correctly a size in android view for all contents?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I have defined a layout containing a `TextView`, an `ImageView` and a `Button`.

In the xml file, I tried using a LinearLayout to contain these views.  That works correctly (I can see my `TextView` then my `ImageView` then my `Button`), but sometimes the `TextView` is too long and I can't see my `ImageView` and my `Button`.

I tried `RelativeLayout`, but it didn't produce the intended result.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/splash" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/storybox"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:autoLink="all"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:text="Texte"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="20px" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button android:id="@+id/image" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Images"
        android:onClick="onButtonDownUpActivityClick" /> 

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply wrap your `LinearLayout` in a `ScrollView`.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:background="@drawable/splash"  >
...
....
....
...

     </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for `ScrollView` which is a layout element that is meant to hold items that are too large for the screen. The `ScrollView` should have only one child (your `RelativeLayout`) and then that child contains the more complex layout.

Check out the Android developers guide for more:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html